# Is it possible to change reference code of an object?

Tags: data

I am thinking about storing reference codes (for example storing "C012345" for Contract object with ID a012E00000LAZPIQA5) so I would not need to use SF API when I need those values. Can they be modified after creating an object?

I tried to find documentation about them or finding them in Object Manager without success. Do they have some other name which is commonly used and easier to lookup in the docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for "auto-number fields." These fields automatically increment by 1 for every record created and cannot be edited by a user at all; the system generates these values on creation. Standard auto-number fields can't be changed to allow editing, but custom auto-number fields can be changed to a text field in order to edit the values, then changed back to an auto-number to resume automatically numbering new records.